# How canon is the majority of the Animatrix?

Tags: movie, the-matrix, the-animatrix

The stories that were written by the Wachowskis are 100% canon, but what about the others? Specifically, "A Detective Story" and "Matriculated"? I noticed a few inconsistencies while watching them.

In Matriculated, one of the characters imparts this bit of info to us:

> "They can't tell the difference. To an artificial mind, all reality is
>   virtual. How do they know that the real world isn't just another
>   simulation? How do you?"

However, the programs in Reloaded can tell the difference because they see their surroundings as code. As for "A Detective Story," we see old timey cars in the background, even though Ash's story takes place in the 90's.

Didn't the Wachowskis work closely with the writers who created these stories?

Comment: Good luck finding **anything** from the Wachowskis regarding what's canon in the Matrix Universe.

Comment: Is it a human delivering that line? They might just be mouthing of in ignorance.

Comment: What makes you think that they don't see the real world in an encoded form as well?

Comment: @Valorum We know they see the Matrix like this: https://media.tenor.co/images/1052091aff3440e8b744de602801de08/tenor.gif In the real world, they see it differently.

Comment: @Deutertraumen - True, but [not that differently](https://youtu.be/JYawJGlEh3k?t=4m47s).

Comment: Just because they see the simulation one way doesn't mean that the real-world couldn't be another simulation that they "visually" process a _different_ way.